# Displaying the same Model data in different ways with different Views

Tags: python, qt, pyqt

Lets say I have some data that looks like this

```
[
    {'name': 'one', 'dir': '/path/to/foo'},
    {'name': 'two', 'dir': '/path/to/bar'},
]
```

I'd like to display this data in two ways -- flat and nested (preferably using QTreeViews for both):

**Flat**

[image: flat tree]

**Nested**

[image: nested_tree]

Ideally, I'd like to use the same model, so that they both use the same data and I don't have to worry about keeping each of them in sync with the other.

The problem is that in the model/view system, heirarchy seems to be something the model is supposed to control, not the view.  How would I go about using the model/view framework in this scenario.

Should I be overriding the Model to return different things depending on the "view type".  Should I be overriding the view to do custom drawing for the "derived" items in the model?  Is there some sort of "itermediate model" that can be used to translate data from the real model into something each view can then display?

Comment: A single model (e.g. a `QStandardItemModel`) can be used represent both flat and nested structures. But it cannot do both *at the same time*. And the same goes for your data. It cannot be both flat and nested *at the same time*. Some kind of re-structuring transformation is required to go from one to the other. Perhaps it would be possible to have a single, low-level data model with adaptors to represent the different structures. But I don't know whether this would be more easily maintainable than simply keeping two separate models in sync.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It should be possible to transform the structure using a proxy model, the [KItemModels](https://inqlude.org/libraries/kitemmodels.html) framework has some examples on how to do that.

However, displaying the same underlying data can also be achieved by having different models operating on the same data.

I.e. a model is only an interface to the data, it doesn't require to own or contain the data.

So you could implement a data container class that can notify about changes and then build two models that use the same container object to present the data in the ways you need.